# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test_fraction'

Tags: python

Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Source Code\Thesis(FINAL)\Music Genre Classifier\classifier_fft.py", line 117, in <module>
    train_avg, test_avg, cms = train_model(None, X, y, "Log Reg FFT", plot=True)
  File "C:\Source Code\Thesis(FINAL)\Music Genre Classifier\classifier_fft.py", line 36, in train_model
    cv = ShuffleSplit( n=len(X), n_iterations=1, test_fraction=0.3, indices=True, random_state=0)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'test_fraction'
```

Code:

```
cv = ShuffleSplit( n=len(X), n_iterations=1, test_fraction=0.3, indices=True, random_state=0)

train_avg, test_avg, cms = train_model(None, X, y, "Log Reg FFT", plot=True)
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It's not obvious what you want, what you have and how you expect to get there with what you've done. Please **give example input and output** needed and *explain* what you've been trying to do to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit (which we can't tell from what you posted), you should read the docs: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.ShuffleSplit.html - it seems there is no parameter `test_fraction`, but there is `test_size`.  It's possible you got your example code from an older version of the library.

Comment: Sorry if I forgot to specify any modules I'm using. I'll try to look on this. Thanks.

Comment: This solved my problem. However I'm having more errors now because it seems I'm writing my project using the older version of the library.

Comment: Great.  If your question is solved, you should mark your accepted answer by clicking the checkmark to the left.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.